# Android:Nexmo Call Api is not working for IVR call

Tags: android, ivr, vonage

I am implementing **IVR calling** in my app.
My voice xml code hosted on public server is below.
I have followed all the steps given on Nexmo website , even getting **status code =0** which means success, but I am not receiving any call. Any idea where I am mistaking?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml version = "2.1" >
   <menu dtmf="true">
      <property name="inputmodes" value="dtmf"/>
      <prompt>
         For sales press 1, For support press 2.
      </prompt>
      <choice dtmf="1" next="#sales"/>
      <choice dtmf="2" next="#support"/>
      </menu>
   <form id="sales">
      <block>
      <prompt>
         Please wait while we transfer the call
      </prompt>
      </block>
         <transfer name="MyCall" dest="tel:+4400000001" bridge="true" connecttimeout="20s"/>
      </form>
      <form id="support">
      <block>
      <prompt>
         Please wait while we transfer the call
      </prompt>
      </block>
         <transfer name="MyCall" dest="tel:+4400000002" bridge="true" connecttimeout="20s"/>
   </form>
</vxml>
```

For IVR Calling i hav used following code snippet

```
if(id == R.id.action_call){
            CallRequest request=new CallRequest();
            request.setApiKey(ApiConfig.NEXMO_KEY);
            request.setApiSecret(ApiConfig.NEXMO_SECRET);
            request.setTo("919582455283");
            request.setAnswerUrl(ApiConfig.ANSWER_URL);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Initiating call...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            App.getRestClient().doMakeCall(new RequestCallback<CallResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onRestResponse(Exception e, CallResponse result) {
                    if (e==null){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }
            }, Constants.CALL_BASE_URL,request);
            return true;
        }
```

Here i got `SUCCESS` in `CallResponse` but not receiving any call.

Comment: Is the number added as test number in your nexmo account?

Comment: @AndroidLearner yes i have already added and verified it on Nexmo portal.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclosure: I work for Nexmo.*

The `status` property on a voice call just means the request was successfully queued (all the parameters were valid, the authentication was correct, etc).

If you pass an `error_url` in the initial request, you'll get some information on why you're not getting the call. The [docs on that are here](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/voice-api/call).

You can also send the support team the `call-id` you get in the response, and see if there's more information they can provide.